# I have a question about the app.vue file in vue

Tags: vue.js

In vue, if you declare   in a file named app.vue as below, the contents of text.vue will be applied to all pages. By the way, I do not want that text.vue to be applied on certain pages. Is there a way?

```
app.vue 
<template>
<div>
<test></test>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I uploaded the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `v-if` to conditionally show certain components depending on the page.

You haven't given any details about how your pages are organized, but assuming you are using `vue-router` and your routes are set up something like this:

```
router.map({
    '/page_one': { name: 'pageOne', component: PageOneView },
    '/page_two':  { name: 'pageTwo', component: PageTwoView },
});
```

Then you can add `v-if` on your component to check the current route's name:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <test v-if="['pageOne'].indexOf($route.name) > -1"></test>
  </div>
</template>
```

The array provided to the code above represents the routes on which you would like to hide the component (you can change the comparison logic to only show the component on routes you specify, if you would like the component to be hidden on the majority of routes).